# Swift logical operators

Tags: swift3, logical-operators

```
var results: [Int] = []
for n in 1...100 {
   if n % 2 !=0 && n % 7 == 0 {
   results.append(n)
}
```

giving me the errors :

> '{' is expected after the if statement
>
> "braced block of statements is an unused closure"

I'm freaking out....
Thanks for any help in advance
p.s - I'm new to stackoverflow so if I did something wrong feel free to tell me what I did wrong and how to improve it

Comment: You're missing a closing bracket, you open two brackets, one for the for loop and one for the if statement, but only close one of them. There also needs to be a space after `!=`.

Answer (score 0):

The error is misleading: There must be a space character after `!=`

```
if n % 2 != 0 && n % 7 == 0
```